# I need your help to solve this problem, it seems very easy but i still get errors every time

Tags: python, if-statement

My goal is: "The user should be able to abandon the game by answering 0 when the program waits for its
response. The program should clearly state that the user has quit the game". But even though I tried, I couldn't write the right code.

```
    print("I guessed a number, try to find it")
    my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    number_to_guess = random.randint(1,9999)
    number_of_tries = 1
    while number_to_guess !=  my_number:
        if number_to_guess > my_number:
            print("Your number must be higher")
            number_of_tries = number_of_tries+1
            my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
        if number_to_guess < my_number:
            print("Your number must be lower")
            number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1
            my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
        if number_to_guess == my_number:
            print("Congrats, you guessed the number")
            print("Number of guesses is:", number_of_tries)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another `if` statement and put it before all the other ones:

```
while number_to_guess !=  my_number:
    if my_number == 0:
        print('Quitting the game')
        exit()
    if number_to_guess > my_number:
        print("Your number must be higher")
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries+1
        my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    ...
```

Comment: yes, I did it earlier but it gives TabError. "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Comment: The code runs ok on my end, sounds like you might have some of the code not aligned properly, as in, something is tabbed out too far or too little.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get input in multiple places rather take input at the bottom for once until while condition getting true.

```
import random

print("I guessed a number, try to find it")
my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
number_to_guess = random.randint(1, 9999)
number_of_tries = 1
while number_to_guess != my_number:
    if my_number == 0:
        print('Quitting the game')
        break
    if number_to_guess > my_number:
        print("Your number must be higher")
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries+1
    if number_to_guess < my_number:
        print("Your number must be lower")
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1
    if number_to_guess == my_number:
        print("Congrats, you guessed the number")
        print("Number of guesses is:", number_of_tries)
        break
    my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

just revise your code:

```
import random
print("I guessed a number, try to find it, quite the game input 0")
my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
number_to_guess = random.randint(1,9999)
number_of_tries = 1
while number_to_guess !=  my_number:
    if number_to_guess > my_number:
        print("Your number must be higher")
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries+1
        my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    if number_to_guess < my_number:
        print("Your number must be lower")
        number_of_tries = number_of_tries + 1
        my_number = int(input("Guess the number:"))
    if number_to_guess == my_number:
        print("Congrats, you guessed the number")
        print("Number of guesses is:", number_of_tries)
    if my_number == 0:
        break
```